# Get results for each topology errors for Polyline or Points?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, topology, python-addin

When you set up a topology to build topology rules for each polyline, or points, is there a way to get the results or summary for each Line Errors?

For example, when you set "Must Not Overlap", "Must not Intersect", "Must Not self-overlap", etc for the line?

The same way for the Point Errors, too.

We know we can symbolized them by set each color in the Symbology tab. The Problem is that it does not show you the numbers of errors for each rule and they only show you the colors. The Generate Summary only shows numbers of errors for each rule.

Does anyone have a way around how to add them to the TOC to display them for each rule ? Is there a script or add-in to be able to do that ? Is this something I should send to ArcGIS Ideas ?

Comment: Unless you are trying to write a Python script to do this using ArcPy, I think your best way forward may be to submit an ArcGIS Idea.  If anyone has an existing script, or add-in suggestion that they are ready to post as an answer then please flag this question for a moderator to re-open it.

Comment: @PolyGeo, Yes, the ArcGIS idea website will move into GeoNet but they have not announce when they will open for everyone to submit their ideas yet. So stay tune for that.